# Panel Data Regression

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data, generalized-estimating-equations

[image]

Here (attached image), FTAs is my "Response Variable" and all the columns in the  right are my "Covariates". It is clearly dependent on time so, there's a strong correlation. I want to find the most significant variable in "Covariates".

I was thinking of using GEE, but can't find the way out properly as R requires "id" in "gee" code which I couldn't crack yet.

Can anybody please turn up with any solution or giving me the proper way out using "GEE".

Comment: Why is the "id" requirement giving you trouble? What is the nature of these data? Does each row refer to a person? A country?

Comment: @MarkWhite Sir, this is the data of Indian tourism, every row of this data corresponds to one year. I don't have much knowledge to transform this dataset into id set up, but somewhere else I have seen the usage of this "GEE" to analyse this same type of data.